# Pass down certain objects when using scope in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that creates its own scope:

```
tsafApp.directive('tsAckGroup', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            ack: '=',
            groups: '=tsAckGroup',
            schedule: '=schedule',
        },
```

However, the are some function in the parent scope I want access to. Is there a way I can "inherit" those functions from the parent scope without redeclaring them (or passing them in the partial) while using `scope:`?

Comment: You should have access to them...or try `scope.$parent`

Comment: It would defeat the purpose of isolate scopes if you could. Of course, it is possible to use `scope.$parent.whatEverFunction()`, but I would **not** recommend it.